# horizontal navigation bar with a horizontal second tier that uses images

Tags: jquery, html, css

can someone please recommend a horizontal navigation bar with a horizontal second tier that uses images. When the user hovers over an image, a mouse over changes the image.

Something similar to this....http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/horizontal-sub-nav-with-css-jquery/ but using images.

i started off working on this and have gotten quite far , but since i used images for the secondary nav bar, i can only get my images to display as vertical rather than horizontal.

I know the offending class is this one below, when the secondary nav is set to horizontal. As when i added different classes....boyLink and girlLink to the  tag, it started displaying vertical. I'm not sure if i should be adding boyLink and girlLink to ul#topnav li span a ?
:

 `/--Show subnav on hover--/
        ul#topnav li span a
        {
            display: inline;
        }`

`ul#topnav
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            float: left;
            width: 970px;
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }`

```
    ul#topnav li
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: Red;
    }

    ul#topnav li a
    {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    ul#topnav li span
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 25px;
        display: none; /*--Hide by default--*/
        width: 970px;
    }

    ul#topnav li:hover span
    {
        display: block;
    }       


    /*--Show subnav on hover--*/
    ul#topnav li span a
    {
        display: inline;
        float:left;
    }


    /*--Since we declared a link style on the parent list link, we will correct it back to its original state--*/
    ul#topnav li span a:hover
    {
        text-decoration: underline;
        display: inline;
    }

    img
    {
        border: none;
    }

    ul#topnav li #homeLink
    {
        width: 51px;
        height: 25px;
        display: block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/nav01U.jpg");
    }

    ul#topnav li:hover #homeLink:hover
    {
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/nav01.jpg");
    }

    ul#topnav li #collectionLink
    {
        width: 97px;
        height: 25px;
        display: block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/nav02U.jpg");
    }

    ul#topnav li:hover #collectionLink:hover
    {
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/nav02.jpg");
    }       


    ul#topnav li:hover #contactUsLink:hover
    {
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/nav06.jpg");
    }

    ul#topnav li:hover span .girlLink
    {
        width: 38px;
        height: 31px;
        display: block;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/snav01U.jpg");
    }

    ul#topnav li:hover span .girlLink:hover
    {
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/snav01.jpg");
    }



    ul#topnav li:hover span .boyLink
    {
        width: 37px;
        height: 31px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/snav02U.jpg");
    }

    ul#topnav li:hover span .boyLink:hover
    {
        background-image: url("Content/Images/Nav/snav02.jpg");
    }



</style>
```

Html Code

```
    <li>
        <a href="collection.aspx" id="collectionLink">&nbsp; </a>

        <!--Subnav Starts Here-->
        <span>
            <a href="girl.aspx" class="girlLink">&nbsp; </a>
            <a href="boy.aspx" class="boyLink">&nbsp; </a>
        </span>
        <!--Subnav Ends Here-->

    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: i have amended code about with the correct answer as per aptwebapps's comment below. basically i added float:left to class -<code> ul#topnav li span a { display: inline; float:left; } </code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your a's display: inline to float: left it will work.

Comment: pure genius that saved me a ton of troubleshooting. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript to do mouseover images any more:

```
a:link { /* normal stuffs */ }
a:hover { /* "mouseover" stuffs */ }
```

As for the structure, I don't see any problem with the css you posted on my end... Perhaps you are trying to put an img tag in the anchor: This is a bad idea. You should load an image as the background css attribute so that it doesn't mess with your formatting.

Comment: hi, yes i am displaying an image in <a> tag, which i'm loading as a background image. Yeah the code above works, but i can't get secondary nav to display as horizontal. also each element under the secondary sub nav needs it's own class, as both images are completely different. as soon as i get rid of boylink and girlLink classes, the navigation displays as horizontal.

Comment: Also i'm already adding the image as a background css attribute or am i missing the point?

Comment: No, you have it right, but you don't need the &nspb; in the a tags. Also, you should use a:hover not li:hover, li doesn't respond (As well)
You need blank space, a placeholder for the secondary nav bar, then you can just change it's absolute position to bring it into line.

I'd be able to help better if you could give me a url to an actual live page to see what's happening.